# Forming a JSON Arrays with Objects using a Python object

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a some variables that I need to dump as a json of the format:

```
{  
  "elements":[  
      {  
          "key":"foo",
          "value":"7837"
      },
      {  
          "key":"bar",
          "value":"3423"
      }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to figure out the right object which would give the above structure upon usin `json.dumps()`. I see that in python, lists give a json array where as dictionaries give a json object while using json dumps.

I am trying something like:

```
x={}
x["elements"]={}
x["elements"]["key"]="foo"
x["elements"]["value"]="7837"
x["elements"]["key"]="bar"
x["elements"]["value"]="3423"
json_x=json.dumps(x)
```

But this still gives me:

```
{"elements": {"key": "bar", "value": "3423"}}
```

which is obviously incorrect.

How to I incorporate the correct dictionary and list structure to get to the above json?

Comment: Why don't you just use `x = {"elements":[{"key":"foo", "value":"7837"}, {"key":"bar", "value":"3423"}]}` ?

Comment: That indeed is usable. I am just trying to better understand the python object/json structure. But what you said works!

Comment: `elements` key has another array (Python list) as a value, not another object. That was your mistake.

Comment: The Python structure that `dumps` turns into that JSON... is the one that `loads` creates from that JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use literal?

```
x = {
    "elements": [
        {"key":"foo", "value":"7837"},
        {"key":"bar", "value":"3423"}
    ]
}
```

---

To fix your code, you need to use a list literal (`[]`) when assigning to `elements` dictionary entry:

```
>>> x = {}
>>> x["elements"] = []  # <--- 
>>> x["elements"].append({})
>>> x["elements"].append({})
>>> x["elements"][0]["key"]="foo"
>>> x["elements"][0]["value"]="7837"
>>> x["elements"][1]["key"]="bar"
>>> x["elements"][1]["value"]="3423"
>>> json.dumps(x)
'{"elements": [{"value": "7837", "key": "foo"}, {"value": "3423", "key": "bar"}]}'
```

But, it's hard to read, maintain.